# case insensitive find in mongodb for usernames in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to find a way to query mongodb in a case insensitive way using PHP because currently when checking a user "Username" and "username" can both be diffrent usernames...

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(array('username' => /{$_POST['value']}/i));
$lowerInput = strtolower($_POST['value']);
$username = strtolower($cursor['username']);
if($lowerInput == $username){
    echo "That username appears to be in our database!";
}
```

I tried this but the cursor only looks for a case sensitive match so it will only lowercase the cursor value if it has one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP Mongo driver has an internal Regex Object:

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(
  array('username' => new MongoRegex("/$_POST['value']/i")
);
```

And btw I strongly recommand to check $_POST value and probably transform you regex to get only username (without more before/after => `new MongoRegex('/^' .  $securevalue . '$/i')`

Edit: my answer wasn't precise: starting anchor allow mongo to use index on this query, if available.

Comment: thanks for that! I knew about mongo having the ability to check regex but didnt know how to use it with PHP!

Comment: MongoRegex is killing the app performance under heavy-load, FYI.

Comment: This query can't use indexes and will be **extremely** slow for large collections because it requires a full collection scan. It doesn't even need to have high load.

Comment: that's why I recommend to use anchors so MongoDB can use an index with starting anchor at least. (and thx for downgrading :p)

Answer (score 10):

Since [MongoRegex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php) has been deprecated, use [MongoDB\BSON\Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-regex.php). Updated example from previous answer:

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(
    [
        'username' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex(preg_quote($_POST['value']), 'i')
    ]
);
```

I wrapped the POST variable in [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to sanitise possibly harmful characters.